# How to get osversioninfo for windows 11

Tags: c++, api, version, windows-11

The **GetVersionEx [Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getversionexa)** can get version upto Windows10 in C++.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    OSVERSIONINFO osvi;    
    ZeroMemory(&osvi, sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO));
    osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(OSVERSIONINFO);

    GetVersionEx(&osvi);
}
```

[Version Helper functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/version-helper-apis) have an **IsWindows10OrGreater** api that can check it's Windows10 or greater but i need exactly the version info of Windows11. Is there any Api like GetVersionEx from there i can get the whole version info of Windows11.

Comment: Have you tried https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/versionhelpers/nf-versionhelpers-iswindowsversionorgreater

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes. I already said that i need details version info. The link you put up, it's return value is boolean which i don't want.

Answer (score 1):

```
 typedef struct _OSVERSIONINFO{
    DWORD dwOSVersionInfoSize;
    DWORD dwMajorVersion;
    DWORD dwMinorVersion;
    DWORD dwBuildNumber;
    DWORD dwPlatformId;
    TCHAR szCSDVersion[ 128 ];
 } OSVERSIONINFO;
```

Why don't you use the `dwBuildNumber` for identifying the Windows 11 Version? Windows 11 build number starts from 22000, and you can search up online the exact build number you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**Direct (but not recommended way):** Both `GetVersion` and `GetVersionEx` are deprecated. That said, you can use the `dwBuildNumber` member of `OSVERSIONINFOEX` returned by `GetVersionEx` if you really want to detect Windows 11. From the [Windows 11 release information page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/release-health/windows11-release-information), a value 22000 and above for `dwBuildNumber` would indicate Windows 11.

**Recommended Way:** Quoting from this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/operating-system-version

> Identifying the current operating system is usually not the best way to determine whether a particular operating system feature is present. This is because the operating system may have had new features added in a redistributable DLL. Rather than using the Version API Helper functions to determine the operating system platform or version number, test for the presence of the feature itself.
>
> To determine the best way to test for a feature, refer to the documentation for the feature of interest. The following list discusses some common techniques for feature detection:
>
> You can test for the presence of the functions associated with a feature. To test for the presence of a function in a system DLL, call the LoadLibrary function to load the DLL. Then call the GetProcAddress function to determine whether the function of interest is present in the DLL. Use the pointer returned by GetProcAddress to call the function. Note that even if the function is present, it may be a stub that just returns an error code such as ERROR_CALL_NOT_IMPLEMENTED.
> You can determine the presence of some features by using the GetSystemMetrics function. For example, you can detect multiple display monitors by calling GetSystemMetrics(SM_CMONITORS).
> There are several versions of the redistributable DLLs that implement shell and common control features. For information about determining which versions are present on the system your application is running on, see the topic Shell and Common Controls Versions.
> If you must require a particular operating system, be sure to use it as a minimum supported version, rather than design the test for the one operating system. This way, your detection code will continue to work on future versions of Windows.